# Uploading .csv file with include and exclude row and col

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Is it possible to remove extra rows when uploading in .csv file in PHP or removing specific words?

Please take a look at my screen shot. I want to exclude those encircled when I process uploading in MySQL.

[image: Screenshot]
[Full Size](http://oi49.tinypic.com/11k8602.jpg)

Here's my code found over the net.

```
<?php

$message = null;

$allowed_extensions = array('csv');

$upload_path = '';

if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {

    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {

        // check extension
        $file = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $extension = array_pop($file);

        if (in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)) {

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {

                if (($handle = fopen($upload_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'], "r")) !== false) {

                    $keys = array();
                    $out = array();

                    $insert = array();

                    $line = 1;

                    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', '"')) !== FALSE) {

                        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
                            if ($line === 1) {
                                $keys[$key] = $value;
                            } else {
                                $out[$line][$key] = $value;

                            }
                        }

                        $line++;

                    }

                    fclose($handle);    

                    if (!empty($keys) && !empty($out)) {

                        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=attendance', 'root', 'root');
                        $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

                        foreach($out as $key => $value) {

                            $sql  = "INSERT INTO `report` (`";
                            $sql .= implode("`, `", $keys);
                            $sql .= "`) VALUES (";
                            $sql .= implode(", ", array_fill(0, count($keys), "?"));
                            $sql .= ")";
                            $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
                            $statement->execute($value);

                        }

                        $message = '<span class="green">File has been uploaded successfully</span>';

                    }   

                }

            }

        } else {
            $message = '<span class="red">Only .csv file format is allowed</span>';
        }

    } else {
        $message = '<span class="red">There was a problem with your file</span>';
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: That's not trying.  That downloading a solution and you wanting to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  without more info - it looks like the rows you want to exclude have less rows than the others (I'm assuming you don't want the blank rows either).

You can use the function

```
$arr= str_getcsv();
```

to read a line of CSV data into an array the do

```
if(sizeof($arr)!=$validCount)
```

on the resulting array you get to exclude lines not of a certain length ($validCount).

Obviously we could get much more in depth for exclusion, but I'm guessing this will get your started.

Note - this requires PHP5.3 or greater.

HTH

R

Comment: is there a way how to import selected columns name only from .csv